# Gaps between striped html table rows

Tags: html, css

I have the following html files:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .table-striped {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            border: 0 none;
        }
        .table-striped td {
            border-bottom-style: dotted;
            border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
            border-color: #999999;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .table-striped tr {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            border-width: 0;
        }

        .table-striped tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #CCCCCC;
        }
        .table-striped tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #ECECEC;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table class="table-striped">
        <tr><td>Line 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Line 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Line 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Line 4</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Despite I set up padding and margins to 0, there are still white thin lines under dotted borders and next cell background.

How to remove them?

I also have example with image, but I would like to do so without them.

I tried the code in Firefox 3.16.6 and Chrome 10.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `cellspacing=0` for table like this:

```
<table class="table-striped" cellspacing="0">
```

Comment: Thanks, found css equivalent: border-spacing

Comment: @sergdev - that's right. However please note that for IE8/7 `border-spacing` property works only if `!DOCTYPE` is specified. http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_tab_border-spacing.asp

Comment: @clairesuzy - Sorry, I didn't check that on `IE 7` as I never used `border-spacing` property only cos of it's compatibility issues with old browsers. Noted. Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem and this was the fix, +1!

Answer (score 2):

```
.table-striped {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0 none;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```